# Invalid Angular route not redirecting correctly

Tags: angular, routes

I'm currently developing a Angular Webapp with routing. I've set up all my routes and they work, but even when I navigate to localhost:4200/jfajfdjsfkdsafjalsdfas/fkdajslfjeae it does not redirect to the given route. It's just a white blank screen with strange console logs:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/fdaf/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
> dafafd:32 GET http://localhost:4200/fdaf/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> dafafd:32 GET http://localhost:4200/fdaf/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> dafafd:32 GET http://localhost:4200/fdaf/scripts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> dafafd:32 GET http://localhost:4200/fdaf/vendor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> dafafd:32 GET http://localhost:4200/fdaf/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:4200/fdaf/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

Only for not nested incorrect routes like localhost:4200/sdfklasjfsafd the redirect works.

Here is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactPageComponent } from './pages/contact-page/contact-page.component';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './pages/landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { ImprintPageComponent } from './pages/legal/imprint-page/imprint-page.component';
import { PrivacyPolicyPageComponent } from './pages/legal/privacy-policy-page/privacy-policy-page.component';
import { PortfolioPageComponent } from './pages/portfolio-page/portfolio-page.component';
import { ServicePagesComponent } from './pages/service-pages/service-pages.component';
import { TeamPageComponent } from './pages/team-page/team-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: LandingPageComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'services',
        component: ServicePagesComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'portfolio',
        component: PortfolioPageComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'team',
        component: TeamPageComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'contact',
        component: ContactPageComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'imprint',
        component: ImprintPageComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'privacy',
        component: PrivacyPolicyPageComponent,
    },
    {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' }),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Edit:
I added a subroute to 'template' path with a parameter :id.

```
{
    path: 'template',
    component: TemplateViewerComponent,
},
{
    path: 'template/:id',
    component: TemplateViewerComponent,
},
```

The base route '/template' works just fine, but when I want to open '/template/1' the same happens - blank page and the weird output.

Comment: Can you share the name of the component which is supposed to be loaded when route `localhost:4200/jfajfdjsfkdsafjalsdfas/fkdajslfjeae` is accessed?

Comment: @Lenzman according to the app routing module it should redirect it to '', which would be the LandingPageComponent.

Comment: Can you share the LandingPageComponent class's decorator? Whatever you have inside `@Component({..})`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it, it was due to `<base href="./" />` in **index.html**

I changed it to `<base href="/" />` and now it works..